Need a mechanical mechanism to design a dog clutch which on pressing a lever engages and then disengages after one revolution
I need a mechanical design that disengages automatically after completing one revolution. I need a dog clutch that engages when we press a lever and disengages when the shaft completes one rotation. I just need a mechanical mechanism for now. Material, torque and RPM calculation are not required.

Do this with a helix.

use a cam .....
